# how to get listed dates out of listed td tags in python using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
<div class="fullwidth singleCalender"><table border="0" cellpadding="4" 
 cellspacing="0">

<tbody>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
<th colspan="7" style="text-align: right; font-weight: normal; padding: 0px 
8px;">Oct&nbsp;2018</th>

</tr>

<tr style="display: table-row;">
<td>Mo</td><td>Tu</td><td>We</td><td>Th</td><td>Fr</td><td>Sa</td>
<td>Su</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none;">
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: table-row;">
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>
<a title="Start of event" style="text-decoration: 
none; background-color: rgb(144, 155, 31); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-
size: 14px; border-radius: 1px; padding: 0px 5px;">10</a>
</td>
<td>
<a title="Start of event" style="text-decoration: none; background-
color: rgb(144, 155, 31); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; 
border-radius: 1px; padding: 0px 5px;">11</a>
</td>
<td>
<a title="Start of event" 
style="text-decoration: none; background-color: rgb(144, 155, 31); color: 
rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; border-radius: 1px; padding: 0px 
5px;">12</a>
</td>
<td><a title="Start of event" style="text-decoration: none; 
background-color: rgb(144, 155, 31); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 
14px; border-radius: 1px; padding: 0px 5px;">13</a>
</td><td>14</td>
</tr>


<tr style="display: none;">
<td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
<td>21</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none;">
<td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none;">
<td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;
</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

how to get 10, 11, 12, 13 values with title = "Start of event" of a tags in td's. from above code in python using scrapy? Can anyone help please? Thanx in advance..!I tried with this code "response.css('div.fullwidth table tbody tr:nth-child(4) td a.Start::text').extract()"
But i'm getting o/p like this "[]".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@title, "Start of event")]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Really? I just tested it. Copied the HTML into `text` variable, manually created `scrapy.Selector(text=text)` and tried `sel.xpath('//a[contains(@title, "Start of event")]/text()').extract()` with success yielding `[u'10', u'11', u'12', u'13']` as expected.

Comment: Linhart..please can you send me through using CSS?